# modify the font size for body and html tags using media queries

Tags: css

I would like to please clarify a doubt. Regardless of the resolution, I am unable to modify the **font-size** of the **body** and **html** tag. I'm trying to change the texts of my page using **rem** (I understand that this measure is based on the **html** or **body** tag, I'm not sure). if I use **rem**, it would simply be enough to modify the size of the **font-size** in the mentioned tags, and so my content would change in size. I am right? or what is the best practice? thank you very much.

```
html, body{
 font-size: 12px;
}

@media (min-width: 576px) { 
  html, body{
    font-size: 12px;
  }

}

@media (min-width: 768px) { 

 html, body{
    font-size: 13px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) { 
  html, body{
    font-size: 14px !important;
  }
 }

@media (min-width: 1200px) {

  html, body{
    font-size: 15px !important;
  }
 }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/a0s4qt8w/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is correct, but you only need to modify the font-size of `<html>` to have rem units work as you wish. Modifying `<body>` will complicate things.

Comment: great, but how can I modify it with media queries?

Comment: Can you mark this as the answer if it solves your issue? Thanks!